# How to integrate seam into an existing project. Or the other way around

Tags: jboss, seam

Is there any documentation about introducing jBoss seam to an old Hibernate/JSF project?

Have tried google, and what I found was: Start new seam project, copy&paste existing code into new project. Would be nice to know a little bit more before starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is probably to add the Seam library to your existing project, and then gradually refactor your code to take advantage of Seam's features. To do this, work through the [Seam manual](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.1.1.GA/reference/en-US/html/) and refactor your code for each Seam feature that simplifies the JSF approach. This includes things like:

- make your JSF action listener classes into [Seam components](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.1.1.GA/reference/en-US/html/concepts.html#d0e3698) (i.e. add one annotation)
- merge action listener and EJB classes (action listeners can be EJBs in Seam)
- inject a [Seam managed persistence context](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.1.1.GA/reference/en-US/html/persistence.html#persistence.seam-managed-persistence-contexts) instead of your existing Hibernate session
- simplify page navigation rules using [Seam navigation syntax](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.1.1.GA/reference/en-US/html/events.html#events.pageaction.navigation)
- migrate views to Facelets, if you are still using JSP.

Basically, Seam will probably give you lots of ways to simplify your existing code, so apply them one at a time to see how they work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be part of the solution:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/en/seam/63-jboss-seam-tutorial-1.html